# What is the best way to check Windows License Status using WMI query

Tags: windows, wmi, wmi-query

I'm trying to find out the best way to check Windows License status using WMI query. The query should return one row indicating the license status and I want it to be as general as possible so that I can run it on many computers and different versions of operating systems.

So far have the following one:

```
SELECT LicenseStatus, Name, ApplicationID FROM SoftwareLicensingProduct
```

The problem is that it returns many rows. For example if there is Office installed it's also included in the query results and I don't know how to limit the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not insist upon pure `wmi` query initially, try *CLI* command given below including output:

```
==>for /F "tokens=*" %G in ('where slmgr.vbs') do @cscript "%~G" /dli

Name: Windows(R), Core edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, OEM_COA_NSLP channel
Partial Product Key: ABCDE
License Status: Licensed

==>
```

Now you could (in a simple `.bat` script) combine it with

```
==>wmic path SoftwareLicensingProduct where "PartialProductKey='ABCDE'" get LicenseStatus, Name, ApplicationID, PartialProductKey, Description /value

ApplicationID=55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f
Description=Windows(R) Operating System, OEM_COA_NSLP channel
LicenseStatus=1
Name=Windows(R), Core edition
PartialProductKey=ABCDE

==>
```

or simply take a look in that `slmgr.vbs` to see *Microsoft* solution.